# Contentful API query for entries that do not have a tag

Tags: contentful, contentful-api

Is there a way to query for entries that don't have a specific tag?

As per the docs to get a collection of entries based with a set of tags we can use `metadata.tags.sys.id[all]=tagA,tagB`

e.g.

```
/spaces/yadj1kx9rmg0/environments/staging/entries?access_token=fdb4e7a3102747a02ea69ebac5e282b9e44d28fb340f778a4f5e788625a61abe&metadata.tags.sys.id[all]=tagA,tagB
```

or we can get a collection of entries that have at least one tag from a list like this `metadata.tags.sys.id[in]=tagA,tagB`

e.g.

```
/spaces/yadj1kx9rmg0/environments/staging/entries?access_token=fdb4e7a3102747a02ea69ebac5e282b9e44d28fb340f778a4f5e788625a61abe&metadata.tags.sys.id[in]=tagA,tagB
```

The 'exists' query appears to test for the existence of any tags `metadata.tags[exists]=true`  not a specific tag.

Is there a way to get a collection that doesn't contain a tag? For example to get all entries except those that have the 'featured' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `nin` like this: `metadata.tags.sys.id[nin]=tagA,TagB`

It will return items which do not have one or more of the comma separated tags you supply.